# to display username on all aspx pages

Tags: asp.net

How to Dispaly the username on all aspx pages....?

Can any one help me in this context.....

am thinking that by using "session object" we can able to do this...bt am not sure

Can any send the code or links

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a mechanism you can use to obtain the current user's username, you could fetch that and add code to your master page(s) to display the name.  There's not really much more that can be said from your question.  (Ask a vague question, get a vague answer.)

And also, if you aren't using master pages, you should be using master pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a master page if you want to display the username on all pages.
Username can be stored in a cookie, session, etc.

Code sample:

```
lblUsername.Text = Session["Username"]
```

Answer (score 1):

System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal user;

```
        user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;

        System.Security.Principal.IIdentity identity;

        identity = user.Identity;

        lblUserName.Text = identity.Name.Substring(identity.Name.IndexOf(@"\") + 1); ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

In First Page (Login page), store the value in Session

```
Session["Username"] = txtusername.text;
```

And rest of the pages, where you want to display the UserName

```
lblUser.Text = Session["Username"].Tostring();
```

For Logout

```
Session["Username"] = null;
```